# thymeleafでdivの閉じタグが出力されない

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

タイトルの通りです。

divの閉じタグが表示されません。

```
        <th:content th:if="${entity.nextShitenIdSameFlg == 1}">
        <p>test</p>
        </div>
        </th:content>
```

↑こちらの部分です。

```
        <th:content th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(entity.shitenname)}">
        <p th:text="${entity.shitenname}"></p>
        <div style="border: solid;">
        </th:content>
```

開始タグはこちらです↑

Eclipse上でも「終了タグ () がありません。」と警告が出ており閉じタグが見つけられていないようです。

ただ閉じタグの直前に書いたpは認識しているようなのでifはしっかり狙いの所で通っています。

何か分かる方いらっしゃればご回答よろしくお願いします。

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="~{layout/component :: head('配属情報一覧')}"/>
<body>
<th:block th:replace="~{layout/component :: header}"></th:block>
<div class="container">
    <th:block th:replace="~{layout/component :: container_top('配属情報一覧')}"></th:block>
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="w-100 m-2">
            <form method="post" th:action="@{/haizokuMaster/list}" th:object="${haizokuMasterListForm}">
            <table class="table-bordered w-100">
                <tr>
                    <td class="p-2 text-center">
                        <label class="m-0">支店</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="p-2">
                        <select class="w-100" name="shitenid">
                            <option th:each="entity : ${optionMapList}" th:value="${entity.key}" th:text="${entity.value}" th:field="*{shitenid}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="p-2 text-center">
                        <label class="m-0">名前</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="p-2">
                        <input class="w-100" type="text" name="koinname" th:value="${haizokuMasterListForm.koinname}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="p-2 text-center ">
                        <input type="submit" value="検索" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 m-2">
            <!-- ページング -->
            <form method="post" th:action="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate}" th:object="${page}">
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li th:if="${!page.first}" class="page-item">
                  <a th:href="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate(page = ${page.number} - 1)}" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, page.totalPages - 1)}" class="page-item">
                    <a th:if="${i} == ${page.number}" th:text="${i + 1}" class="page-link"><span th:text="${i+1}">1</span></a>
                    <a th:if="${i} != ${page.number}" th:href="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate(page = ${i})}" class="page-link"><span th:text="${i+1}">1</span></a>
                </li>
                <li th:if="${!page.last}" class="page-item">
                  <a th:href="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate(page = (${page.number} + 1))}" class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            </form>
            <!-- ページング -->
        </div>
        <th:content th:each="entity:${list}">
            <th:content th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(entity.shitenname)}">
            <p th:text="${entity.shitenname}"></p>
            <div style="border: solid;">
            </th:content>
                <div class="card mb-3 mr-1" style="max-width: 375px;">
                  <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <img th:src="${entity.filedataString}" class="card-img" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                            <a th:href="@{'/koinMaster/detail?id=' + ${entity.id}}" th:text="${entity.koinname}">
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <p class="card-text"><a th:href="@{'/koinMaster/detail?id=' + ${entity.id}}" th:text="${entity.yakushokuname}"></a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <th:content th:if="${entity.nextShitenIdSameFlg == 1}">
            <p>test</p>
            </div>
            </th:content>
        </th:content>
<!--        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <tr>
              <th>支店名</th>
              <th>年齢</th>
              <th>名前</th>
              <th>役職</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="entity:${list}">
              <td><a th:href="@{'/shitenMaster/detail?id=' + ${entity.shitenmaster.id}}" th:text="${entity.shitenmaster.shitenname}">name</a></td>
              <td><a th:href="@{'/koinMaster/detail?id=' + ${entity.id}}" th:text="${entity.age}">name</a></td>
              <td><a th:href="@{'/koinMaster/detail?id=' + ${entity.id}}" th:text="${entity.koinname}">name</a></td>
              <td><a th:href="@{'/koinMaster/detail?id=' + ${entity.id}}" th:text="${entity.yakushokuname}">name</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table> -->
        <div class="w-100 m-2">
            <!-- ページング -->
            <form method="post" th:action="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate}" th:object="${page}">
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li th:if="${!page.first}" class="page-item">
                  <a th:href="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate(page = ${page.number} - 1)}" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, page.totalPages - 1)}" class="page-item">
                    <a th:if="${i} == ${page.number}" th:text="${i + 1}" class="page-link"><span th:text="${i+1}">1</span></a>
                    <a th:if="${i} != ${page.number}" th:href="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate(page = ${i})}" class="page-link"><span th:text="${i+1}">1</span></a>
                </li>
                <li th:if="${!page.last}" class="page-item">
                  <a th:href="@{/haizokuMaster/pagenate(page = (${page.number} + 1))}" class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            </form>
            <!-- ページング -->
        </div>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">戻る</a>
    </div>
</div>
<footer th:replace="~{layout/component :: footer}"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 質問の最後に書かれているコードはthymeleafの入力となるテンプレートでしょうか？何か所かタグが閉じられていなかったり、開始タグと終了タグの対応がとれていないように見えます。3行目のheadが閉じていない。62行目のdivが閉じていない。83行目から85行目のタグの順序が入れ子になっている。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。すいません、3行目のheadに関しては質問時に何かおかしくなったみたいなので実際は閉じています。修正しておきます。63行目のdivが今困っていまして、こちらを83行目のdivで狙ったタイミングで閉じたいです。分かりにくくてすいません。

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleafのテンプレートはhtmlとして妥当なものになります。
最終的にどうすべきか、というのは質問文の内容だけでは意図が理解できないので提示できませんが、例えば

```html
<th:content th:if="${entity.nextShitenIdSameFlg == 1}">
        <p>test</p>
        </div>
        </th:content>
```

について言うと、

```html
<th:content th:if="...">
  <p>...</p>
  <div>...</div>
</th:content>
```

となる必要が有ります。
(`div`の開きタグが必要; ただしおそらくこうしたいわけでは無いでしょう)

---

やりたいことは、 `div` に `style` を適用するかどうかを何らかの条件で判定したいのかなと思いました:

```html
    <th:content th:each="entity:${list}">
      <th:content th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(entity.shitenname)}">
        <p th:text="${entity.shitenname}"></p>
      </th:content>
      <div th:style="${!#strings.isEmpty(entity.shitenname) ? 'border: solid'}">
        省略
      </div>
      <th:content th:if="${entity.nextShitenIdSameFlg == 1}">
        <p>test</p>
      </th:content>
    </th:content>
```

参考: [4 スタンダード式構文 > 条件演算子](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf_ja.html#%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E5%BC%8F%E6%A7%8B%E6%96%87)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。分かりにくくて申し訳ないです。thymeleaf初心者でしてそもそも実現可能かどうかも疑問ですが。。リストを回す中で、th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty(entity.shitenname)}"でdivを開始→th:if="${entity.nextShitenIdSameFlg == 1}"が来たタイミングでdivを閉じたいです。jspで似た事が出来たのでthymeleafでも再現できるのかなと思ったのですが。。